# Git and XCode: Merging .xcodeproj gives binary warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git

I am working with branches and wanting to merge with my master, but the files inside of my .xcodeproj are causing huge issues.

Constantly getting errors about overriding them, that they are binary files, etc etc.

What do I need to do to never have to worry about this? It is driving me nuts!

NOTE: I have a .gitignore file in my master that ignores these files, but not in my branch. Not sure what to do about that.

Answer (score 1):

In the root of the project (eg, same directory as `.git`), add a git ignore file

```
.gitignore
```

With a line that says

```
.xcodeproj
```

Then remove the `.xcodeproj` file from the repo...

```
git rm --cached /path/to/.xcodeproj
```

Then add the .gitignore file

```
git add .gitignore
```

Then commit

```
git commit -m "Removed .xcodeproj; added ignore pattern to excluded it"
```

Comment: Well, I do have a .gitignore file in my master, but not in my branch. The one is master does what I want, but I know there will be conflicts when I try to merge.

Comment: @NicHubbard: how far apart is your branch from the master?  If you are 25 commits off, it could be difficult in any event.  I would close XCode, make a copy of the .xcodeproj, delete it, and then merge master into your branch, and then update the .gitignore, and then put the .xcodeproj back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a .gitignore file to specify that file to be ignored by git.

Comment: Well, I do have a .gitignore file in my master, but not in my branch. The one is master does what I want, but I know there will be conflicts when I try to merge.